# How to get Google earth vector layer geometry type

Tags: javascript, google-earth

How do I get the feature type of a vector layer in google earth (is polygon or polyline or point). 
I can get the type of the layer (vector, imagery or terrain). 
But I can't get the feature type of the vector layer...
Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Edit:

```
var layers = ge.getLayerRoot().getFeatures().getChildNodes();
```

After this line, I am getting an array of the layers that I have in my google fusion. 
I am getting three type of layers: imagery, terrain, and vector. 
I can recognize which one is. But I can't recognize the type of the vector layer - is it line, polygon or point.

Comment: Show us some code (how do you create the overalys, ...)

Comment: I add the layers via google fusion. I don't have any code that add the layers

Comment: See, taht's another important information needed for us to help you. Also why have you tagged javascript when you don't want any code?

Comment: Because I want to know the type via javascript code... I have a enterprise server

Comment: I am sorry, but from your question it is still impossible for me understand what you want exactly.